# Why is bash sourcing .bashrc in non-interactive mode when working via ssh?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, openssh

I have a CentOS VM to which I log in using SSH. I appended the following line to `.bashrc`

```
echo "from ~/.bashrc: (pid $$)"
```

and the following line to `.bash_profile`

```
echo "from ~/.bash_profile"
```

When I log into the VM and run `ps` I get the following output

```
user@laptop:~ $ ssh vmcentos
Last login: Sun May 17 04:48:24 2020 from 192.168.122.1
from ~/.bashrc: (pid 1821)
from ~/.bash_profile
[admin@localhost ~]$ ps -H -o pid,command
  PID COMMAND
 1821 -bash
 1844   ps -H -o pid,command
[admin@localhost ~]$
```

This output is what I expect since the shell I log into is an interactive login shell and thus the `.bash_profile` file is sourced which in turn sources the `.bashrc` file.

Now I log out from the VM and execute the following command

```
user@laptop:~ $ ssh vmcentos 'sleep 60; echo $-'
from ~/.bashrc: (pid 1901)
hBc
user@laptop:~ $
```

then I log into another `ssh` session on the VM and inspect the process table

```
[admin@localhost ~]$ ps -eH -o pid,command
  PID COMMAND
(... more output here...)
 1900       sshd: admin@notty
 1901         bash -c sleep 60; echo $-
 1914           sleep 60
(... more output here...)
```

As far as I understand the shell that `ssh` executes (process 1901) is non-interactive (because of the `-c` option and also because the `$-` variable contains no `i` character) and non-login (because `ARGV0` is not `-bash` and no `--login` option is provided). Thus neither `.bashrc` nor `.bash_profile` should be sourced. Yet the output of the command clearly shows that `.bashrc` was sourced. Why?

I used a standard CentOS installation with the standard `openssh` configuration.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332531/why-does-remote-bash-source-bash-profile-instead-of-bashrc

Comment: Side note: if you test stuff like that, remember that unconditionally printing stuff from the shell init files can break programs like `scp` and anything else that might try to do something automatically and interpret the output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to the manual, it's supposed to do that](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html):

> Bash  attempts  to  determine  when it is being run with its standard input connected to a network connection, as when executed by
>   the remote shell daemon,
>          usually `rshd`, or the secure shell daemon `sshd`.  If Bash determines it is being run in this fashion, it reads  and  executes 
>   commands  from  `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists and is readable.

Bash's startup files are weird.

Comment: Note that it's only if someone uncommented the `/* #define SSH_SOURCE_BASHRC */` line in `config-top.h` in the source code of bash before compiling bash.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, hmm, it's mentioned as a fact in the manual, though. Looking at the code it looks like `SSH_SOURCE_BASHRC` controls another test that checks for SSH's envvars, while the test for stdin being a network connection is unconditional, a couple of lines later. (Didn't check changes over versions, there's some suspicious `#if 1` lines there) https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c?h=bash-5.2#n1136

Comment: Yes, that's a very controversial feature, and there's been a lot of back and forth over the years, including at various distros which enabled or not that feature, at times with patches over upstreams IIRC. Note that with ssh, stdin is a pipe (or tty in rlogin mode or with `-t`), stdin being a socket was with rshd which nobody uses any longer these days.