# ssh localhost command not found

Tags: bash, ssh

Hi I am new to linux and trying to get a program to work.

I followed the following instructions:

```
Edit your ~/.bashrc file to set up the environment for the caffe U-Net software:

export PATH=$PATH:/home/unetuser/u-net/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/unetuser/u-net/lib
```

Now the expected bahviour is that when i run `caffe` I get the expected output, and indeed that works as expected.

However when i try:

```
ssh localhost caffe
bash: caffe: command not found
```

Why can i not use the `caffe` command with `ssh`?

according [to this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332531/why-does-remote-bash-source-bash-profile-instead-of-bashrc) using `ssh localhost <command>` loads the ~./bashrc profile which has the correct command path.

Comment: "_the expected bahviour is that when i run `caffe` I get the expected output_". Ignoring `ssh` for a moment, does this step work?

Comment: yes it works as expected.

I can also connect to ssh localhost and then run caffe.

It is the full command ssh localhost caffe that returns the :bash: caffe: command not found

Comment: Hi I have carefully read the answer. Accordingly it specifies that when a ssh command is run then It will not start a login shell, therefore ~/.bashrc is what will be read. 

As my commands are added to the ~/.bashrc file I expect them to be read when executing ssh localhost 'command'. However the command is not found despite being in the ./bashrc

Comment: Please try `ssh localhost 'getent passwd $USER' | awk -F: '{print $1,$7}'` (for `localhost` as per your question). First field should be your expected username. Is the second field `/bin/bash` - and if not, what is it?

Comment: betaglutamate /bin/bash
yes works as expected

Comment: Put your path exports in `.bash_profile` instead.

Comment: "_Edit your ~/.bashrc file to set up the environment for the caffe U-Net software_" ... You have added the `PATH` modification to your own `/home/betaglutamate/.bashrc` haven't you, and not `/root/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running a remote command like this `ssh` does not run the command with a login shell (that is, it does not source `~/.bashrc`. If you'd like to force it to do so, you can run the command with `bash -l -c` :

```
ssh localhost bash -l -c 'caffe'
```

Comment: Yes it does. Create a single line `.bashrc` with `echo This is .bashrc`. Then try `ssh thathost id`. You'll see the message printed before the output of `id`

Comment: so this answer works. I am not sure if this fixes the problem as I believe the program calls ssh localhost caffe. I will mark this as correct if it fixes the issue.

Comment: @roaima, I tried your experiment and did not get the message printed out of `.bashrc` Maybe the behavior changes across versions? I'm using OpenSSH 7.4.

Comment: Ok so i do not see the message  `echo This is .bashrc` when in ~/.bashrc I have marked this as the correct answer because it explains what I am seeing and is producing the expected behaviour. I may open another question if I am having issues with the program